# Position button inside a div to the bottom right

Tags: html, css

I would like the button to be positioned at the bottom right of the red colored `div`. I used `padding-bottom` and `margin-bottom` properties but that does not seem to work. Could anyone please help?

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  padding: 8px;
}

.box {
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.button {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">
  </div>
  <div>
    <button class="button">Click</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I just put your code in and I got this. Unless I misunderstand, this is what you want right?
I think you have it correct, you must be doing something else wrong. Can you send the entire html and css file? Thanks
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ixatZ.jpg

Comment: I want the button to be positioned inside the red colored div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.button {
    float: right;
    position:relative; 
    transform:translate(-5px,-25px); //x and y controls
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I have just answered the same thing to other question. ... Use `position:relative`. I see the point why people refrain from using it. But really ain't no shame. Especially when there isn't a parent-child relation between the elements.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  padding: 8px;
}

.box {
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}



.button {
  float: right;
  position:relative; 
  top: -22px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">
  </div>
  <div>
    <button class="button">Click</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow! that was it.

Comment: this is hacky soution

Comment: Ideally button should have been inside red div. But it wasn't

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to the other answers using `display: grid` instead. This is easier for the browser than using position absolute or float!!

```css
/* ignore */ body { margin: 0 } * { box-sizing: border-box } /* ignore */

.container {
  display: grid;
  width: 50vw;
  height: 100vh;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  padding: 8px;
}

.box, .button { grid-area: 1/1/-1/-1 }

.box { border: 1px solid red }

.button { margin: auto 0 0 auto }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">
  </div>
  <div class="button">
    <button>Click</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: good one, I've removed mine because this is better.

Comment: @dippas thank you, I've been on a mission lately to try get away from `float` and `position` in order to optimise css by minimising recalculation before painting. I love this little grid hack

Comment: I don't use `float` for years, maybe 7 or 8 years or even more, its a mess

Comment: @dippas agreed, I've been heavily reliant on `position`, but the OP used float so thought I should mention both